# Is it good to put a player into detention (jail) or just kick the user from a server?

Tags: psychology, games, experience, logic

I am developing a game server in an open-world game where players can do whatever they want. Once however my staff encounters a rule breaker I advise them to, by their judgment on how bad it is, to kick or (temporarily) ban the user.

On many concurenting servers you can also see that they put players into "detention"* for X time depending on how badly the rules were broken.

In my opinion this is useless as you are removing the user from the game without disconnecting him (he can only chat, but sometimes even that is blocked). I decided not to implement such a thing on my server.

What is the best for a user? Wouldn't the user be more upset after being put into detentin/jail? Wouldn't he/she just leave on his own which eventualy becomes the same as a kick? (just more frustrating?)

- Detention: your character is moved to a closed game area where no one can reach you, you are in a small space and you cannot do anything except just look around a very small room. Sometimes participating in the chat is also disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on your game. It's very similar to dealing with trolls: if their only goal is to upset other users and to break the rules, then detention is exactly the kind of attention they're craving for. In this case kicking the user or putting them into detention might have the same effect. They might just come back as a different character and the problem starts again.

So instead of taking the effort to build a jail for such kind of users I'd suggest to deal with them as trolls, which means: ignore them. Rather build a feature where all actions of the user are only visible to them. This way breaking the rules doesn't have any effect and will tire out the user rather quickly.

This being said on trolls. If however your users are just testing out the limits and don't want to upset others constantly, then a simple temporary block (always with a clear description *why* they've been blocked) might help.

Comment: Thats one big advantage of suspensions over full kicks: Gives less incentive to just go and create a new account.